# rails triggering js action on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails4 app. I'd like to trigger some js events on page load, but only if user comes from a given page.

By default all the comment replies are hidden on the `post#index` page. If user clicks on a div then the corresponding replies become visible.

Now I want to have a given `post_comment_reply` div visible by default on page load, if a user comes to the page via clicking on the notification belonging to the `post_comment_reply`.

What is the preferred way in rails to do that?

js

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-post-comment-reply', function (event) {
  var post_comment_id = $(this).data('pcid');
  $('#post-comment-replies-' + post_comment_id).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a cookie would work, as suggested by another user. You could also check the `request.referrer` in rails to see where they came from.

Couple of ways to handle triggering the js from there. You could pass the referrer value to the js with something like:

```
<div class="some-class" data-referrer="<%= request.referrer %>">
```

Then in your js, if you're using jQuery:

```
if ($('.some-class').data('referrer') == 'whatever_url'){
  // run your code
}
```

You could also put a conditional directly in the view. Probably not as clean but something like:

```
<% if request.referrer == 'whatever_url' %>
  <script>
    // code to run
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Which one is the preferred way? If the latter and the `request.referrer == xy` will be evaluated true then what I should do? Something that I know is setting some params but I don't like that solution, it's ugly in the address bar?

Comment: Thanks al lot! Just so hard to choose, since I don't know the pros/cons neither the rails conventions.

Comment: I think either approach is fine. I set cookies for a lot of things, but I try not to make that the first resort. Setting a cookie is a valid way to solve the problem, too, though.

Comment: toddmetheny, I ran into one more problem. So `request.referrer` is not exact enough since in my case the referrer can be anything. User gets here by clicking on notification dropdown that is available on all the pages. What's the best approach in that case?

Comment: Sry, I accidentally touched enter. Updated my comment.

Comment: Pass a parameter that varies based on the selection and then check for the existence of that parameter.

Comment: Can you somehow make the param invisible or delete after js has run? I mean I think it's ugly to have the params in the address bar. Not a nice UX.

Comment: I don't really think it's a problem. It's the language of http and the internet. Don't know a way around it but shouldn't actually affect user experience.

Answer (score 1):

you can attach a cookie on the given page , in link onclick event, then delete it after showing the comments box.